# Oracle : Execute Query with LOV selected value

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, lov

I need to run a query with a value that is selected from a LOV.

I've got the next setup :

- a block named "MENIU"
- a table named "MENIU" with a column "ID_MENIU".
- a LOV named "LOV_MENIURI"
- a parameter named P_IDMENIU
- a button on the form named "Alegeti Meniul"

In order to run a query with the value selected from the LOV I've tried this :

- LOV return item "ID_MENIU" is set to PARAMETER.P_IDMENIU
- in the pre-query of block MENIU I've assigned the PARAMETER.P_IDMENIU value to MENIU.ID_MENIU
- Button "Alegeti Meniul" has the next "when-button-pressed" trigger code :

  ```
  declare 
      success boolean;
  begin
  Enter_Query;
  success := show_lov('LOV_MENIURI');
  Execute_Query;
  end;
  ```

My problem is that when pressing the button for the first time nothing happens, if I press the button a second time LOV window appears and the query is executed twice.

A GIF with the outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need that enter_query call.

```
begin 
  if show_lov('LOV_MENIURI') then
    execute_query;
  end if; 
end;
```

When calling the execute_query built-in you'll fire the pre-query trigger, setting the where clause using the value returned by the LOV.